# Best way to specify inherited-class return type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a parent class `Animal`:

```
class Animal {
  name: string;

  eat(): void;
  sleep(): void;
  
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And I can have potentially a large number of child classes e.g.,

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  bark(): void;

  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  meow(): void;

  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}

class Mouse extends Animal {
// ... and so on
```

and I have a function that returns an unknown-at-compile-time child of Animal, how should I define the return type apart from doing `Dog | Cat | Mouse | ...` or `any`?

```
const getAnimalByName(name: string) : /* what goes here? */ {
  /* ... */
};
```

I presume if I specify `Animal` and use that Animal object later on, I could be met with errors like "Property `bark()`  does not exist on type ..." if I call `getAnimalByName('dog');`. Is there a way to specify a return type that allows for this flexibility?

Comment: does `getAnimalByName(name)` allow other inputs such as `getAnimalByName('Murphy')`  which returns a Dog?

Comment: If  you don't know based on the string what class you get, you can use `Animal`. You can later check with `instanceof` and you will get access to derived class emthods

Comment: @ABOS no it would only be allowed to specify the actual name e.g., 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir that would work yeah. Was just wondering if TypeScript had some special trick where you could specify `ClassDerivedFromX` as an actual type if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

We could use function overloading. The drawback is that you will need to manually update the overloads whenever you add or remove an animal type.

```
class Animal {
  name: string;

  eat() {};
  sleep() {};
  
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  bark() {};

  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  meow() {};

  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}

function getAnimalByName(name: 'dog'): Dog;
function getAnimalByName(name: 'cat'): Cat;
function getAnimalByName(name: string) {
  switch (name) {
    case 'dog':
      return new Dog('dog');
    case 'cat':
      return new Cat('cat');
  }
  return null;
}

const animal = getAnimalByName('dog');
// => Dog
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoa15mQFMAuaCAFwCdF4BzAbix2kLHIAoBKTAX0dwghChAA5de-aM2AB7eBUoBXYORmV2+IqQU1a3bLlzkAFoggA6TYWgBePAUKSeWZ1lCQYAERm0WAD3JCeAATGAQUNExmACMwSgBrcQw+JlxZeSplVXUrbSpdfWYBRRFCHIdOJxcmdyhoAGE2f0CQsKRUdANoIhkAdySU6TkFLLUNBzzqOkLDMhKy8aJK5mdXADNFeBVEOWhaQnJwjoAhAE8AOQdFkmgAcmCfW85SbwYsDa3yHfg9g6O0M6XIjXUi3YBsJ6kRrkRgfba7faHdoAi5XXJkfLTKICXqIcjAYzQa4zQzgiDWe6PYhFQyUA6KSg-eCEXrQV7sSm0J6SNKQCng8i3amzXB08gMpkshpsDkC7krZhiiV4RQgECMVzpCjQMDI9B2RH-ECAq6c+VAA)

Comment: That's a nice idea yeah. As you said, can get a bit messy once there are many `Animal` types which is my concern